# Fused location provider - location recorded only when WiFi On

Tags: android

Phone: Nexus 4, Android 4.4.2, Google Play Services 4.3.25 (1117461-036)

Goal:

I want to record GPS positions via the fused location provider.

The code works the "standard" way": using location client and location request, registering for updates in onConnected with the pending intent starting intent service for handling of each location update received.

The `LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY` accuracy is used.

**The problem is this**

- I turn on *Location* in settings (I see Mode: high accuracy there), and then press the button to start recording of positions
- However, no updates are received.
- Then, I turn on WiFi and suddenly, the updates are received.
- The strange part is that **I don't have to connect to any WiFi network. It is enough that I just turn WiFi on in the settings**
- Now, when I turn off the WiFi completely, and then start recording again, I get the updates as expected

It seems that even when using the high accuracy, the fused location provider isn't using GPS provider until WiFi is on.

Did anyone experience the same behaviour?

Comment: GPS provider takes a while to start responding.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the case. It really feels like if turning the WiFi on were causing the fused location provider to be activated.

Comment: I have the same problem! I thought Fused Location just doesn't work with GPS only, but it seems it works, but only when WiFi is on! Very strange, and still I haven't found any clues about why wouldn't it work, and I've searched everywhere...

Comment: Wait a minute, I just realised it's wrong assumption. Android is still not using GPS, only it reads wifi networks around and provides location according to what's around you. So still, gps doesn't work with fused location, and it's amazing